# Neo4j apoc.convert.toTree is not showing duplicate children with unique relationship

Tags: neo4j

I have two nodes A and B (A->B) connected via two relationships. Those 2 relationships are unique. For example, you can think of the two rels as two paths from A to B at two different times. Converting them to one relationship is not viable at this time.
[image]

For displaying in UI, query result should be a tree structure. Used following query to get the tree

```
MATCH p=(n:Label1 {name:'main'})-[:calls*..2]->(m)
WITH COLLECT(p) AS ps 
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(ps) yield value
RETURN value;
```

the resulting tree is

[image]

Preferred result is

[image: expected result]

How can I get a tree with duplicate children is more than one relationship exists between same two nodes?

Thanks.

Comment: I am afraid we `apoc.convert.toTree` doesn't support that. If a node is connected via multiple relationships to the same node. The rel properties get overridden.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor, is there way to do this within neo by some other means

Comment: @jose_bacoy has provided an alternative does it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I offer a hack on this SO question. Although it is not exactly the resulting nested document as the apoc function but I think it can server your purpose.

```
MATCH p=(n:Label1 {name:'main'})-[:calls*..2]->(m)
// each path will be returned
WITH COLLECT(p) AS ps, p, n
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(ps) yield value
// return node n and it's relationships as a nested document
RETURN {_id: ID(n), _type: labels(n), node:n, relationships: collect(value['calls'][0])} as result
```

Sample result:

```
[
  {
    "result": {
      "_id": 31,
      "_type": [
        "Label1"
      ], 
      "node": {
        "name": "main"
      },
      "relationships": [
        {
          "calls.y": "prop y",
          "_type": "Main",
          "_id": 32
        },
        {
          "_type": "Main",
          "_id": 32,
          "calls.x": "prop x"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: @jose-bacoy-ds.webflow.io,  thanks a lot of the solution. It works for single level but for multi level hierarchy, the view is a bit different. I ended up building the tree in my java service. I figured it may be more efficient as it reduces the result size between neo and service plus don't need to do the extra work in the query.